# Autowiring of beans generated by EasyMock factory-method?

Tags: java, spring, easymock, autowired, factory-method

I have a problem that seems really strange to me. I have the following setup:

An interface:

```
package com.example;

public interface SomeDependency {
}
```

A spring component:

```
package com.example;

@Component
public class SomeClass {
}
```

A spring test config with a mocked bean generated by EasyMock:

```
<beans ....>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>

    <bean id="someInterfaceMock" class="org.easymock.EasyMock" factory-method="createMock">
        <constructor-arg value="com.example.SomeDependency" />
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

And a unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/testconfig.xml")
public class SomeClassTest {

    @Autowired
    SomeClass someClass;

    @Autowired
    SomeDependency someDependency;

    @Test
    public void testSomeClass() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(someClass);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeDependency() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(someDependency);
    }
}
```

The project compiles and the tests pass without any problem, i.e. autowiring of both *SomeClass* (a "real" object) and *SomeDependency* (a mock object generated by EasyMock) succeed.

However, if I change the implementation of *SomeClass* to:

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {

    @Autowired
    SomeDependency someDependency;
}
```

both tests fail because

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.example.SomeDependency] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

So my questions are:

1. Why does Spring fail to autowire the dependency to *SomeClass* (when it succeeds autowiring the same dependency to *SomeClassTest*)?
2. How can I change the *SomeClassTest* or *testconfig.xml* to make the tests pass?

Comment: In reality the class represented by *SomeClass* is part of a framework. Consequently, it cannot easily be updated, at least not within reasonable time.

Dependencies:

- Spring: 3.0.5.RELEASE
- EasyMock: 3.0

**Edit:**

As of Spring 3.2 RC1, the problem with generic factory methods and mock objects has been [solved](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/11/07/spring-framework-3-2-rc1-new-testing-features/).

/Mattias

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems the order of the definitions in the xml actually matter when using factories to create beans with autowiring. If you place the declaration of `someInterfaceMock` above `component-scan` it will work.

Some clarification why: When Spring tries to autowire `SomeClass` it searches for a bean of type `SomeDependency`. At this stage `someInterfaceMock` is still a factory so Spring checks the signature of the factory method `EasyMock.createMock(...)` which returns `<T>` so Spring only finds an `Object` which isn't the type required.

A better way would be to use Spring's `FactoryBean` interface to create your mocks.

Here is a basic implementation that should work:

```
public class EasyMockFactoryBean<T> implements FactoryBean<T> {
    private Class<T> mockedClass;

    public void setMockedClass(Class mockedClass) {
        this.mockedClass = mockedClass;
    } 

    public T getObject() throws Exception {
        return EasyMock.createMock(mockedClass);
    }

    public Class<T> getObjectType() {
        return mockedClass;
    }

    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    } 

}
```

Here is the bean definition (the order won't matter!):

```
<bean class="com.example.EasyMockFactoryBean">
    <property name="mockedClass" value="com.example.Dependancy"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks! The order did the trick, but I think that I will use the EasyMockFactoryBean implementation, considering that it is likely that I will have to mock other dependencies later.