# How mock spring component during tests without extracting interface from it?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, interface, mockito

There is a spring componet with `@Component` annotation, it is just java class (not interface) with annotated `@Autowired` fields. I am trying to create mock like that:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
    >
  <bean id="myComponent" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="com.MyComponent"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

And got an exception that some of fields are not autowired. This happens, because when Spring see `<constructor-arg value="com.MyComponent"/>` it try to instantiate `MyComponent` bean and pass it to factory method.

I have tried to extract interface from component, in that case mocking works, but is there a way to make it working without extracting interface?

**Also**

I have tried adding `type="java.lang.Class"` but got same errors.

```
  <bean id="myComponent" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg  type="java.lang.Class"  value="com.MyComponent"/>
  </bean>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us the code of class and the definition of the beans which need to be autowired, please.

Comment: First of all, with Spring and Mockito, I would always prefer to work with interfaces. In your case, why don't you simply add another (mocked?) bean and insert that into your constructor via `ref`...? 
But what is the bean you need to put into the constructor really a java.lang.Class object? Sounds strange.

Comment: "why don't you simply add another (mocked?) bean" - it is exactly what is going on at line `class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock"`

Comment: "But what is the bean you need to put into the constructor really a java.lang.Class object" - see attentively at `class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock"`. There is no constrcutor call. There is a factory method call in `Mockito` class.

Comment: Sorry, my fault there, wrong thinking. There's a note here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457239/injecting-mockito-mocks-into-a-spring-bean , that the declaration has to be before others, but I assume you got that already...

Comment: It works for me, when I do....  `<bean id="testService" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
  <constructor-arg value="com.example.util.TestService" />
 </bean>` -> Leads to a Mock of TestService, even if TestService is a class and has some `@Autowired` fields declared. Could you add the exception you are getting and the autowwired parts of your `myComponent`?

Answer (score 2):

Spring cannot autowire the bean because the type of the created bean is `java.lang.Object` and not `com.myComponent`. Apparently the order of the definitions in the XML matters as well.

Jayway has a very nice blog post about this: [Spring Integration Tests - Creating Mock Objects](http://www.jayway.com/2011/11/30/spring-integration-tests-part-i-creating-mock-objects/)

You can create a `FactoryBean` which returns the correct class:

```
public class MockitoFactoryBean<T> implements FactoryBean<T> {

    private Class<T> classToBeMocked;

    /**
     * Creates a Mockito mock instance of the provided class.
     * @param classToBeMocked The class to be mocked.
     */
    public MockitoFactoryBean(Class<T> classToBeMocked) {
        this.classToBeMocked = classToBeMocked;
    }

    @Override
    public T getObject() throws Exception {
        return Mockito.mock(classToBeMocked);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return classToBeMocked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Using this factory bean, you can create a config like this:

```
<bean id="myComponent" class="com.yourpackage.MockitoFactoryBean">
    <constructor-arg name="classToBeMocked" value="com.myComponent" />
</bean>
```

This will mock your component and the object type will `com.myComponent`.

---

**Update**

This is the original answer and explanation (using EasyMock): [Autowiring of beans generated by EasyMock factory-method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340007/autowiring-of-beans-generated-by-easymock-factory-method/6340391#6340391)